# Tem diferença entre checksum e hashcode?

Tags: terminologia, ciência-da-computação, hashcode, checksum

Imagino que tendo dois nomes diferentes eles têm funções diferentes, mesmo parecendo sendo a mesma coisa, geral códigos curtos numéricos baseando-se em um objeto, mas quais são elas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O *checksum*, como o nome diz, é uma forma de fazer uma checagem de dados, através de uma soma do conteúdo. Mas essa soma não precisa ser tão simples assim, na verdade é uma forma de usar alguma matemática para fazer todo o conteúdo de objetos virar um número.

Ele é um *hashcode*, porque todo *hashcode* é gerado de forma semelhante, cada um com sua fórmula. Mas ele tem o objetivo específico de identificar se algo está "batendo", ou seja, ele funciona como um dígito verificador, igual ao que usamos no CPF por exemplo.

O objetivo é te dar uma proteção contra uso errado do objeto, ou de alterações que não deveriam ter nele. E a fórmula deveria refletir isso, já que ele deve minimizar o risco de uma alteração acabar gerando o mesmo código.

É impossível pegar um objeto grande e gerar um *hashcode*/*checksum* que seja sempre diferente de outro conteúdo, mas a fórmula deve facilitar que isso não aconteça em muitas situações. Imagine que algo perca a integridade, mas o *checksum* gere o mesmo código depois, como identificar se teve uma alteração sem comparar tudo individualmente?

Isso é até desejável em um *hashcode* para outros fins, mas não é tão importante.

E há uma tendência de precisar que o *checksum* tenha o resultado rapidamente. Não que o *hashcode* possa ser tão lento em muitas situações, embora em algumas pode e deve ser.

O objetivo do *hashcode* é ter um indicativo simples das diferenças entre objetos, em alguns casos para segurança, em outros para algum mecanismo técnico, sendo o mais comum usar em uma tabela *hash*. Em muitos casos pode-se até mesmo escolher apenas algumas partes de um objeto para usar no *hash*, algo que não faz sentido no *checksum*. A melhor fórmula para ele pode ser uma que permite uma boa distribuição nos *buckets* da tabela *hash*.

Usar o termo correto passa a informação mais precisa do que se deseja, quais os princípios deve observar quando for implementar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).